# Pythonic way to connect classes?

Tags: python, class, oop

I am struggling to find a pythonic way for the interaction of classes with instances of other classes.

Look at this example for better understanding:

```
class Item():
    def __init__(self, name):
        if g.exists(name):
            name = name + '_new'
        self.name = name

class Group():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
    def add(self, item):
        self.data.append(item)
    def exists(self, name):
        for i in self.data:
            if i.name == name:
                return True

g = Group()
g.add(Item('one'))
g.add(Item('one'))
```

My question points to line 3 of the code above: How can I avoid to call a specific instance of another class? This is a challenge that I do face for quite a while now without having any idea how to make my code more general (and less specific).

Comment: Since the name depending on the `Group` instance state, it seems like the `Group` instance should be responsible for determining the `_new` name, not the `Item` instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to make it less generic - using arguments (also improved other bits too):

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, class_):
        if class_.exists(name):
            name += '_new'
        self.name = name


class Group:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def add(self, item):
        self.data.append(item)

    def exists(self, name):
        for i in self.data:
            if i.name == name:
                return True


g = Group()
g.add(Item('one', g))
g.add(Item('one', g))
```

Comment: But then I have to mention the Group class two times in one call. I already thought about passing the parent class as an argument, but that seems to be semi-convincing... ;-)

Comment: You can create classes in a loop tho, so that argument could be filled in automatically

Comment: @Matiiss `class_` is a terrible name. You *aren't passing it a class*. You are passing it a `Group` object, which is not a class, it is an *instance of the class `Group`. A better name for that argument would be `group`.

Comment: @Ulrich yes, well, this is still the best way to handle thsi. The fundamental problem is your *design*, your `Item` requires a `Group`, and your `Group` requires an `Item`. Circular dependencies are best avoided as much as possible. Sometimes they are the best solution you can come up with... but try to think about ways you can avoid this

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the reason I named it `class_` (better would have been `instance`) is because OP wanted it to be universal so not necessarily an instance of Group but any instance that has `exist()` method (need checks for that too tho)

Comment: @Matiiss That seems contradictory, the OP wants it to be a duck-typed Group. That isn't universal. But even taking that for granted,  `class_` still doesn't make sense for that. "class" is not a generic name for an object, you should just use "obj" or something. classes *are specific types of objects*, namely, objects that inherit from `type`. You might as well call it `list_` or whatever. `Group` is a class, `Group()` is not

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I guess I will have to learn more about this terminology (about types and classes and objects). Also OP said he wants to make the code more generic/less specific so that would mean he is not limiting the method in Item class to just Group class but to any class that has `exist()` method